# Javascript making the return of a function into a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I make this `app.locals.user` to be the return value instead of a function? Right now I have to run `app.locals.user().name`.

How can I make it so I can just run `app.locals.user.name`?

```
    app.locals.user = function(){
            if(typeof(req.session.user) != 'undefined'){
                console.log(req.session.user.name.full);
                return req.session.user;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use [__defineGetter__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/DefineGetter) :

```
app.locals.__defineGetter__("user", function() {
    if(typeof(req.session.user) != 'undefined') {
        console.log(req.session.user.name.full);
        return req.session.user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Edit** : __defineGetter__ seems to be deprecated, here is a better way :

```
Object.defineProperty(app.locals, "user", { get : function() {
    if(typeof(req.session.user) != 'undefined') {
        console.log(req.session.user.name.full);
        return req.session.user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

just `return whateverVariable;`

Javascript isn't typed so you can't really do anything to put this in the function signature.

```
function foo() {
    var x = { a : 10, b : 20};
    return x;
}

var y = foo();
debug(y.a);  //prints 10
```

Comment: well at the moment I am returning the function, is there a way i can make it a inline variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can immediately execute the function in order to store the result as a variable:

```
 app.locals.user = (function(){
            if(typeof(req.session.user) != 'undefined'){
                console.log(req.session.user.name.full);
                return req.session.user;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        })();
```

Comment: @VartanArabyan, that's true, but I thought that's what you were asking for. You cannot have a variable that automatically updates itself -- if that's what you want, then make it a function and call it every time.